# Updating Excel Spreadsheet Data with Swift

Tags: swift, excel, database

I have created a Xcode project that has a spreadsheet inside the project folder and am using the xlsxreaderwriter to connect to the excel sheet.

My project can read from the excel spreadsheet and update it while the program is running. My problem is that the program does not save the excel spreadsheet connected with the new data. My console shows that it is saving but when I open up my actual spreadsheet file it looks like the original version that I created.

Below is the two functions I created to set up the cell references and to save the data which I put in the viewDidLoad.

```
private func getExcelCells()  {

 let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DatabaseV1", ofType: "xlsx")!

 //Open the spreadsheet, get get the first worksheet, and select cell B5
    let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(path)
    let sheet: BRASheet = spreadsheet.workbook.sheets[0] as! BRASheet
    let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet

 // Creates variables that are type CellModel
    var cat1 = CellModel(categoryTitle: "Best DJ", firstCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "B5"), secondCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "B6"), thirdCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "B7"), fourthCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "B8"))
    let cat2 = CellModel(categoryTitle: "Best SGA", firstCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "E5"), secondCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "E6"), thirdCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "E7"), fourthCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "E8"))
    let cat3 = CellModel(categoryTitle: "Best Greek Organization", firstCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "H5"), secondCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "H6"), thirdCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "H7"), fourthCell: worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "H8"))

// Add the variables created above to the array excelCells
    excelCells += [cat1, cat2, cat3]
   cat1.cellOne.setStringValue(nominees.optionA)
  let data =  worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "A5").stringValue()
    print(cat1.cellOne.stringValue())
    print(data)


    }

 private func saveExcelFile() {
   let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DatabaseV1", ofType: "xlsx")!
        let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(path)
        let sheet: BRASheet = spreadsheet.workbook.sheets[0] as! BRASheet
        let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
        worksheet.save()
        spreadsheet.save()
    }
```

Here are the results I get back I my console but again when I open the spreadsheet from my computer files it is not updated.

```
some("2014-15")
Optional("Nominee 1 ")
Best DJ : Best DJ
Best SGA : Best SGA
Best Greek Organization : Best Greek Organization
TVC Data has nominees 2014-15
2018-05-16 12:51:48.375702-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : worksheets/sheet1.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.432046-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : [Content_Types].xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.437702-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : docProps/app.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.440162-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : docProps/core.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.442317-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : styles.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.471786-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : theme/theme1.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.474184-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : worksheets/sheet1.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.519212-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : sharedStrings.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.526377-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : _rels/workbook.xml.rels
2018-05-16 12:51:48.530246-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : xl/workbook.xml
2018-05-16 12:51:48.540307-0400 xlsxreaderwriter[18952:668623] Saving target : _rels/.rels
2014-15 2015-16 2016-17 2017-18
```

Comment: The Bundle location is read only. You will need to save it at the documents directory or somewhere else.

Comment: @LeoDabus could you guide me towards implementing this?

Comment: @LeoDabus, hi, did you ever solve this? If yes, please can you show us how? Thank you.